# Error: expected identifier or undeclared variables when running Mongoose code on Windows and WSL2

Tags: mongoose

I am trying to run the example code from https://github.com/cesanta/mongoose however, I'm getting this error after running make and following the installation instructions. I've also tried running it on WSL2 but to no avail. However, if I run the examples on my linux laptop, everything works fine.

```
❯ make
gcc                       main.c mongoose.c        -W -Wall -Wextra -g -I.   -lws2_32             -DMG_ENABLE_LINES  -o example
In file included from main.c:6:
mongoose.h:1:1: error: expected identifier or '(' before '.' token
    1 | ../../mongoose.h
      | ^
main.c:15:23: warning: 'struct mg_connection' declared inside parameter list will not be visible outside of this definition or declaration
   15 | static void fn(struct mg_connection *c, int ev, void *ev_data, void *fn_data) {
      |                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.c: In function 'fn':
main.c:16:13: error: 'MG_EV_OPEN' undeclared (first use in this function)
   16 |   if (ev == MG_EV_OPEN) {
      |             ^~~~~~~~~~
main.c:16:13: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
main.c:18:20: error: 'MG_EV_HTTP_MSG' undeclared (first use in this function)
   18 |   } else if (ev == MG_EV_HTTP_MSG) {
      |                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.c:20:9: warning: implicit declaration of function 'mg_http_match_uri' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   20 |     if (mg_http_match_uri(hm, "/websocket")) {
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.c:23:7: warning: implicit declaration of function 'mg_ws_upgrade' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   23 |       mg_ws_upgrade(c, hm, NULL);
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
.....
.....
make: *** [Makefile:22: example] Error 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this issue on Windows. This is an issue specific to Mingw I believe and the way that a .c/.h file uses a relative path without a #include statement.

In the examples directory you are in, there will be a:

- mongoose.c
- mongoose.h

If you look at the contents of those files they will just be

```
../../mongoose.c
```

If you change (both) of those files so they read

```
#include "../../mongoose.c"
```

Then Mingw will resolve the file and compilation will succeed.